# What’s the difference between access to a broken HDD with special software vs. typical access through an OS?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

My HDD broke, but I could extract data from it using special software. The computer did detect the HDD but I could not enable it in the disk manager. If the HDD is only readmode, the i should be able to atelast copy data from the drive using windows manager. But I couldn’t. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An OS needs the filesystem to be healthy (at least to some degree) to mount it. The partition table must be valid to easily tell where on the disk the filesystem(s) is.

A probable scenario is the filesystem couldn't be mounted but the tool you used was able to recognize (some of) its structures and retrieve some (not necessarily all) files one by one. It's possible by directly reading sectors from HDD, without relying on the filesystem driver implemented by the OS. The tool uses its own knowledge on how such and such filesystem is supposed to look like. Saving files from broken filesystems is one of such tool's jobs. A particular file may or may not be saved, depending on which sectors are damaged, unreadable etc.

Since you didn't specify what special software you had used, this is only my hypothesis; a plausible one though. Certainly there are tools that work this way.